# What PC programs or iPad applications are there which allow you to plot cylindrical/spherical polar graphs?

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates, math-software

I've been trying to get my head around the use of cylindrical and spherical polars to plot graphs. I feel that the easiest way to do this would be to try plotting some, but I'm struggling to find a program which allows you to do so.

Anyone know of any PC programs or iOS applications which allow you to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Give CalcPlot3D a look. It's a marching cubes plotter, with implicit and parametric inputs in cartesian, cylindrical, or spherical coordinates. I use it extensively for rendering hypertoric surfaces.

http://web.monroecc.edu/calcNSF/